# is this a good example of a closure?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, closures

I saw this as an [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Practical_closures) and didn't understand why this was a Good Thing (TM).

```
function makeSizer(size) {  
      return function() {  
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
      };  
    }  

    var size12 = makeSizer(12);  
    var size14 = makeSizer(14);  
    var size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

Why is the above better than the below?

```
function makeSizer(size) {  
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
    }  

    var size12 = makeSizer(12);  
    var size14 = makeSizer(14);  
    var size16 = makeSizer(16);
```

What does it do differently? Obviously, I'm missing the point...

EDIT: Adding rest of code (full code was in link)

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;  
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;  
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;  

<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>  
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>  
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
```

Comment: I must admit this was badly worded question. Late night posting will do that :) What I meant to ask was why would I use a closure as opposed to just doing `onclick = makeSizer(14);`? Where makeSizer(14) is referring to second version of the function. I'll do what Kooilnc suggested and play around with jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `size` is variable that is enclosed. Calling `makeSizer(12)` returns a function reference that 'remembers' 12. This function reference is assigned to a click handler on an element (see the rest of the code in the MDN-example). It says: if you click me, call (execute) `size12`. On clicking thus the font size of the body becomes '12px' because the function reference returned from `makeSizer(12)` is executed (with the enclosed value of 12).

If you would've used the function you would have resized the font immediately.

```
function makeSizer(size) {  
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';  
}
var size12 = makeSizer(12);  
var size14 = makeSizer(14);  
var size16 = makeSizer(16); //=> now the font-size of the body is '16px'
```

Think what would happen in this scenario when you did:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
```

Would anything happen if you clicked `#size-12`?

The MDN-page you linked to links to a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vnkuZ). Try it out!

*Good* or *bad* are things I happily leave to the more religious part of the community. I would say this closure is useful, even handy perhaps.

Comment: And in great contrast, the version of makeSizer that only sets the body's fontSize will return the undefined value, rather than a function suitable for using as a button's onclick handler.

Answer (score 1):

none of them is better, but they behave differently.

The first won't actually size until you call the returned function as follows:

```
size12();
```

Your second example first declares a function and then calls it 3 times. You immediately set the size to 12px then 14px and finally 16px.

Answer (score 0):

What are your criteria for "good"?

In the first example, you create some functions that then must be called to do the work. The size is held in a closure, difficult to see any benefit. You might want to do:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    return function() {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}

var setSmall = makeSizer(8);
var setMedium = makeSizer(10);
var setLarge = makeSizer(14);
```

or similar, so now you just call:

```
setSmall();
```

The function in the second case should be called something like *setSize*.

Another use of a closure would be:

```
var setSize = (function() {
  var sizes = {small: 8, medium: 10, large: 14};

  return function(size) {

    if (sizes.hasOwnProperty(size)) {
      document.body.style.fontSize = sizes[size] + 'px';
    }
  }
}());

setSize('small');
```

Whether they are "good", "bad" or whatever depends on your criteria for classifying them as such.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `makeSizer` returns a function. In the second example, it doesn't return anything, and has a misleading name. The two are completely different.

The reasoning in the first example is that `makeSizer` is a function-factory; it makes "sizer" functions. `size12`, `size14`, and `size16` are particular "sizer" functions, made by `makeSizer`. If one of them is called later, it will set the font size.

In the second example, you first set the font size to 12, then to 14, then to 16, and at each stage you save the uninteresting return value into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you have there is *not* an example of a closure.

Wikipedia tells us the definition of a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) is a *"function together with a referencing environment for the non-local variables of that function."*

More simply, it's a function that 'encloses' variables of the surrounding scope.

A good example would be something like this:

```
public Func<int> ClosureExample()
{
    int a = 1,
        b = 2;

    Func<int> closeIt = () => a + b;
    return closeIt;
}
```

Let's really look at what's going on in this.  We declare two integers, then use the lambda expression/closure/anonymous method (all are valid names for the definition assigned to the first-class function generic) to return the first-class function that will be used to perform this calculation, *using the enclosed variables*, somewhere else.

You can say that closeIt is enclosing integers a and b; those variables do not belong to the closure, yet they are being used by it.

Comment: The MDN example (first function in my example) of a closure **is** a closure. So I am not understanding how you are saying it is not.

Comment: `public Func<string> Foo()
{
  int a = 1, b = 1;

  return () => a == b ? "Yes!" : "No...";
}

public void Bar()
{
  Func<string> foo = Foo();
  foo();
}`

The method Foo returns a lambda expression that references the integers A and B in the method; these variables are said to be 'enclosed' by the method.

Bar calls Foo.  The function enclosing those variables is returned and stored in foo.  When foo is called, "Yes!" is returned.

foo enclosed a and b; when Foo went out of scope, those should have been GC'd.  However, they're held onto...at least until Bar() goes out of scope.

Comment: But the parameter `size` is coming from the parent function makeSizer and the anonymous function is enclosing `size`. Is it not? Whether the parameter is passed to the parent function or declared in the parent function but obviously before the anonymous function, shouldn't matter. In both instances the variable would be in parent scope.

Comment: What I was showing above is that enclosure is not exactly the use of an anonymous method; a closure encloses variables from the parent scope.